# How to make Unique Identifiers for CSS JQ Models in a PHP loop

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, css

So I'm wondering how to set unique identifiers for every model the loop creates

I'm looping through a custom post type to create content based on every post that exists. I want to popup modals on the read more with the full content and not just the excerpt but in the loop. I'm not sure how to make every modals identifier unique and then read it in the Javascript.

Here's the loop:

```
 <div class="row">
           
             <?php
                    $review = new WP_Query(array('post_type' => 'review', 'posts_per_page'=>'-1', 'order_by' => 'post_date', 'order' => 'DSD'));
                    if($review->have_posts()) : while ($review->have_posts()) : $review->the_post();
            
                    
            ?>
            <div class="col-lg-3 monial-block mg-top-m">
            
                
            
                    <div class="flex-r">
                        
                        <?php 
                        $rating = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), "wpcf_stars", true);
                        
                         for ($x = 0; $x < $rating; $x++) :
                        ?>
                          <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
                         <?php endfor; ?>

                        <i class="fa fa-bookmark" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    </div>
        
                    <p>
                     <?php the_excerpt() ?>
                    </p>
                    <button id="myBtn">Read More</button>
                    <div class="flex-r names">
                        <hr class="test-hr">
                        <h4 class="test-name">
                            <?php the_title() ?>
                        </h4>
                    </div>
                    <div id="myModal" class="modal">

                  
                        <div class="modal-content">
                        <span class="close">&times;</span>
                                <?php the_title() ?>
                            <?php the_content(); ?>
                        </div>

                        </div>
            </div>
            <?php endwhile; ?>

            <?php else : ?>

                <p><?php __('No Reviews'); ?></p>

            <?php endif; ?>
        
        </div>

    </div>
```

Here's the JavaScript

```
    var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks on the button, open the modal
btn.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

Here's the CSS

```
.modal {
    display: none; /* Hidden by default */
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    height: 100%; /* Full height */
    overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
  }
  
  /* Modal Content/Box */
  .modal-content {
    background-color: #fefefe;
    margin: 15% auto; /* 15% from the top and centered */
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #888;
    width: 80%; /* Could be more or less, depending on screen size */
  }
  
  /* The Close Button */
  .close {
    color: #aaa;
    float: right;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: bold;
  }
  
  .close:hover,
  .close:focus {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
```

Maybe I don't even need Unique Identifiers but I'm just pretty sure it's the issue. The 1st element is the only one that has a working model, the rest have the content filled but don't popup when I click on them.

Comment: Give them unique IDs instead of "myBtn". If its in loop, try giving "myBtn-0", "myBtn-1" and so on. And then apply click listeners in loop by selecting elements by ID in same fashion. Or you can directly add click listeners to buttons in your PHP by adding JS to do so.

Comment: U mind posting an Example for me Shyam?

Comment: Maybe something like `var date = new Date(); element.id = "btn-" + date.getTime()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be done like this:

above `for ($x`... add

```
$modalCount = 0;
```

Then change button and modal html like so:

```
<button id="myBtn<?php echo $modalCount++; ?>" data-modal="myModal<?php echo $modalCount; ?>">Read More</button>
...
<div id="myModal<?php echo $modalCount; ?>" class="modal">
```

This will add a number to current id, so ids will look like this

- myModal0
- myModal1
- ...

You can then select all buttons with data-modal attribute

```
// since you are using jQuery
$("button[data-modal]").click(() => {
    const modalId = $(this).data("modal"); // this could make issues
    // if it does, use .attr("data-modal")
    const modal = $(modalId);  // this is the modal you are looking for
})
```

Comment: I see, Its not working for me but im suspecting its because your asking it to listen for a click event on the modals but the modals dont exsist untill the button is clicked or am I goofing it?

Comment: Yeah my bad, the solution with queryselectorall can be used only inside buttons, not for opening, goof on my side. The solution with ids should work anyway.

Comment: im pretty lacking when it comes to jq/js xD do u mind posting a example of the JQ/js for me on the ID solution

Comment: I want to take a look at my own

Comment: Interesting so i Can just say modal.style.display = "block" as an example y?

Comment: Since its wrapped in jquery, you would need to say modal[0].style.display... , or you can just utilise jQuery and say modal.css({ display: "block" })

Comment: Hmm cant get it to work, But dam I dint know you could do that learning alot here XD

Comment: Try debugger and check if modal variable has correct value, and if the selector gets any elements from your page. Another thing that could go wrong is lack of jQuery on page. Does your console shows any errors?

Comment: Actually no Modal Veriable returns a huge ammount of arary values when logging it https://imgur.com/undefined

Comment: Can you please take a look my solution?Let me know If it is working or not

Comment: Im noticing all the modal IDs and such are coming out as either Modal5 or Modal4

Comment: I'd suggest using simply `$(modalId).show();`. Also if you want to hide all the others that are shown, you could prelude that line with `$(".modal").hide();` to hide all modals before showing the one clicked.

Comment: @Someguy I missed that the for cycle is not till the end, so we have to create our own variable, the code is edited and will hopefully work now.

Comment: Awesome Stuff I manager to figure that out just now then noticed u posted. But yes that was the missing piece :) Thanks a mil and thanks for all the input @IncredibleHat

Comment: can you please take a look at my edited snippet, it's more simple and easiest.